# How to monitor all my apache wildcard vhosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, virtualhost

I have a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
ServerAlias *.domain.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

My goal is to have a web page with independent statistics for each subdomain (CPU usage, Mem usage, Requests/sec etc.) and to have the possibility to define alerts and to view the statistics history.

What open source tool do you recommend?

Comment: I've the same question. I have a awstats tool but i need a monitoring like [this example of cacti](http://forums.cacti.net/about15475.html&highlight=vhost), the problem in this example is that mod_watch is old and not supported in nowadays. Are there any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: Try this template for cacti http://forums.cacti.net/about17995.html&highlight=apachestats which uses mod_status.

And here http://forums.cacti.net/about25227.html you can view what graphs includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [cacti](http://cacti.net/) which fits with what I wanted, it has filters for dates and I can write my own plugins (for alerts).

Answer (score 0):

**webalizer** is sort of OK, it produces at lot of statistics in diagrams and numbers in a webinterface by examaning the apache logfiles.

You can't define alerts with it though, but you could **munin** to do that, at least for the cpu and mem usage, don't know about setting alerts for req/sec for apache, perhaps there's a plugin. Munin is a breeze to install compared to nagios.

Comment: Thanks, but webalizer and munin doesn't have alerts and neither history